# Pretty-printing JSON output

Tags: json, format, pretty-print

This is my code to display JSON output from my database.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $row_array['option_id'] = $row['option_id'] . "<br>"; 
    $row_array['option_name'] = $row['option_name'] . "<br>";  
    $row_array['option_value'] = $row['option_value']. "<br>";  
    $row_array['autoload'] = $row['autoload']. "<br><br>";
    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response, $row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

The output goes like this:

```
[{"option_id":"262
","option_name":"carl
","option_value":"manere
","autoload":" 

"},{"option_id":"263
","option_name":"John
","option_value":"John Smith
","autoload":" 

"},{"option_id":"265
","option_name":"James
","option_value":"James Doe
","autoload":" 

"},{"option_id":"266
","option_name":"Dwight
","option_value":"Dwight Howard
","autoload":" 

"}]
```

I want the output to go like this, instead.

```
[
  {
    "option_id": 262,
    "option_name": "carl",
    "option_value": "carl manere",
    "autoload": " "
  }, . . .etc
```

How can I format it like this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

Comment: hi @barry_127. i have used that json_encode but the output is kinda messed up. is there a way i can output it like the way i wanted.

Comment: Ah I see. json isn't designed to be outputted pretty. It's to be as compact as possible to so the size to load is small. Maybe use <pre> but this breaks the json code. Another option is the use of a browser plugin to pritty print the json code I use JSONview for Mozilla but I'm sure there are plenty of others